# Callback Function is Undefined Within Itself

Tags: javascript

I have a callback function:

```
function map(item, callback) =>
    Object.fromEntries(
        Object.entries(item).map(callback)
    )

const replaceDollarCb = ([key, value]) => [key.replace('%$%', '$'), typeof value === 'object' && value !== null && !Array.isArray(value) ? replaceDollarCb(value) : value]; // Here I get "undefined is not a function".

UtilObject.map(subQuery, replaceDollarCb);
```

It keeps failing to find the function itself (`replaceDollarCb`). I've used `this` and even changed them to non-arrow functions.

Comment: Can you at least provide a working example here or jsFiddle or somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that the method is `undefined` within itself, it's that you're not passing the expected array of `key` & `value` as arguments.

You'll need to recall your method with `map` not directly `replaceDollarCb` to make it work as I think you expected.

```js
const map = (item, callback) =>
  Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(item).map(callback)
  )

const replaceDollarCb = ([key, value]) => [key.replace('%$%', '$'), typeof value === 'object' && value !== null && !Array.isArray(value) ?
  map(value, replaceDollarCb) :
  value
];


const subQuery = {
  "foo%$%": {
    "subfoo%$%": "bar"
  }
}
console.log(map(subQuery, replaceDollarCb));
```

Answer (score -2):

Hi :) I'm not sure I understand your question, but `map` is reserved word in JavaScript as map function - thank you, Quentin, on arrays - exists and defining/overriding it (I'm not sure what's first lines meant to do) is bad idea.

Next problem is that you use `replaceDollarCb` before defining it. Did you mean recursion?

EDIT:
I'm also not sure why you "define" map first and use UtilObject.map too. Maybe that's something that could help you :)

Comment: `map` is not a reserved word, there is a `map` method on arrays but that can be overridden.

Comment: "Next problem is that you use replaceDollarCb before defining it." — This does not appear to be true.

Comment: Thank you, I edited it :) Yes, map on arrays, but I still think that modifying native methods is bad.

Comment: There's no suggestion that they are modifying a native method. Just creating a new method on on a custom class

Comment: There is no class there too (I don't see definition of UtilObject), so i was guessing and hoping it would help author :) Mario is right, JSFiddle would be helpful :)